# Gradle from 6.9 to 7.5: extended configuration from another subproject is empty

Tags: gradle, migration

Gradle from 6.9 to 7.5:  extended configuration from another subproject is empty.

subproject1 build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.10.0'
}
```

subproject2 build.gradle

```
evaluationDependsOn(':suproject1')
configurations {
    foo.extendsFrom(project(':subproject1').configurations.compileOnly)
}

println "foo: " + configurations.foo.asPath
```

configurations.foo is empty. It should contain

```
group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.10.0'.
```

For 7.5, configurations.compileOnly.asPath: canBeResolved=false. So need to extend it.

For 6.9.x: configurations.compileOnly.asPath: works.